# How to calculate total response time in jmeter?

Tags: testing, jmeter, performance-testing

I have send 10 consecutive http requests in jmeter.
I have stored output as csv file.

```
endTimeMillis   responseTime    latency sentBytes   receivedBytes       responseCode
1357279943.984  1426             1426     347             287           200

1357279944.685  1888             1888     347             287           200
..............
..............
```

In above output file response time displayed by each request. But i need to calculate total response time for 10 requests.

How to calculate total response time in jmeter?

Comment: When you say threads, you mean samples or really threads, if you mean threads why would you need that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a [Transaction Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Transaction_Controller). Put elements times of which you want to sum under it. Transaction controller will then appear in all your listeners. Its load and latency times will be sums of those parameters of its nested elements.

> Note that this time by default includes all processing within the controller scope, not just the samples, this can be changed by unchecking "Include duration of timer and pre-post processors in generated sample".

Comment: thanks.I have use simple controller instead of Transaction controller.because Transaction controller add extra 1 more request like it will generate 11 requests instead of 10 request.this is not happen in simple controller

Comment: @ILLA But you won't get total response time if you'll use Simple Controller